# D8016 несовместимые параметры командной строки /zi и /gy-

Tags: c++

Скачал библиотеку fltk-1.1.10 и при сборке решения "fltk" показывает 63 ошибки D8016. Опишите, пожалуйста, поподробнее ответ, так как новичок в программировании.

Answer (score 1):

> Вы выбираете "изменить и продолжить" `/ZI`, чтобы была возможность
>   исправить код во время отладки, но и "отключить связывание на уровне
>   функций" `/Gy-`.
>
> Эти два параметра не будут работать вместе, так как Вы не можете
>   просто изменить одну функцию в середине кода. Поэтому просто выберите
>   один из них, например, измените `/Gy-` на `/Gy`.

Оригинал ответа здесь: [Visual Studio error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Gy' command-line options are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43141537/6125029)